# Best practices to get data and save it

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I have an android application and in one of my activities I am making a call to get say "Customers", this call is made to an external API, when I get the response I get it as a JSON object. The problem i am having is that I have a ListView in the activity and when you click on of its items it shows you the details but then when you hit the back button I have to make the call again to populate it. In Samsung Galaxy 4S it seems to keep the data of the list view but in the HTC android incredible it's blank. So what I did is, make it rebind OnResume(), this fixed the issues for both BUT the consequence is making another call to that server. When its 10 or 100 customers it doesnt matter but I know that there are some accounts that have up to 5000 and I am sure it will crash.

What are my options to improve performance on this issue with Android?, I tried a static variable but at some point that object got cleared too.

How do Android applications usually handle this cases where the data is retrieved from API's and they need to be stored through out the application and there is no need to make another call for the same information?, I was thinking on static object but i want to make sure I do this the right way.

Comment: Check out [this article](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html). It was designed specifically for this question ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a couple of options.

1) You can cache the data in memory. For example you can make a static cache or cache the data within the Activity or the App object. If you are doing this in only one view and if it is not a lot of data, this might be an ok solution. However, if you have to do this for many activities and there is a lot of data that has to be cached, you might want to go for option 2. Also storing data in memory in android, does not mean it won't be garbage collected (in some cases, even if you have a reference to it.)

2) You can cache the data in the internal storage and refresh it from time to time.
You can find more info about the internal storage and how to use it here: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#filesInternal

Basically, you store the response within the internal storage under a specific identifier. The next time you open the activity, you check if the storage has data for that identifier and if yes, you read it and display it. If no, you make the API call.

Keep in mind, that you will have to refresh the cache from time to time.

Answer (score 0):

I had the problem with `ListViews` on my application too. What I did is that I wrote a custom adapter and that solved the issue..

However the thing you can do is to make a global variable and save the returned results to it. When your application wants to call the server, check the variable, if it's null make the call, if it's not then just draw the `ListView` with the already fetched data..

Keep in my mind, to implement a refresh button, you need to skip the check.